# How can I override Twitter Bootstrap dropdown hover in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-9

This works in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox. **But not in IE9.** I want to remove the blue background from the dropdown-menu hover.

I have a twitter bootstrap dropdown-menu.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li>
    <a href="/users/sign_out">Sign out</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In my overrides.css (loaded after bootstrap.min.css)

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover, .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
  color: red;
  background-color: white;
  background-image: none;
}
```

However, in IE the `background-color` and `background-image` is not working, it's still the twitter bootstrap blue. The `color` works fine, it is red when I hover.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is a jsfiddle with my example: http://jsfiddle.net/tcpxq/

Comment: Try `background: none`

Comment: @bob_cobb that doesn't seem to work either. That only causes my curser and background to flash violently.

Comment: @Rob good idea -> http://jsfiddle.net/tcpxq/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover, .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
  color: red;
  background-color: white;
  background-image: none;
  filter: none;
}
```

Comment: The filer:none was the key for me. Thanks Robert! This was so difficult for me to diagnose.

Comment: Thanks, I've been looking for this for a couple of hours!

Comment: The background-image: none was key for me.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21854138/changing-the-background-for-bootstrap-dropdown-a-on-hover for another example.